# Regular Expression excluding a specific number

Tags: c#

I have the following validation expression:

```
ValidationExpression ="^(?000000007)(?!000|666|900)[0-8][0-9]{2}(-)?(?!00)[0-9]{2}(-)?(?!0000)[0-9]{4}$"
```

And this validation expression doesn't allow first three digits to be 0, last 4 digits to be 0 and and 4th and 5th digit to be zero.

How can we exclude a this number from validation `000000007`?

Comment: Start with : ^[1-9]{5}

Comment: I am extremly sorry. it is a typo the correct regular expression is ^(?1000000007)(?!000|666|900)[0-8][0-9]{2}(-)?(?!00)[0-9]{2}(-)?(?!0000)[0-9]{4}$ and i want to exclude this number (000000007) from validation

Comment: [Edit] the question and just fix the typo.

Comment: I have the feeling that a list of `if` statements might be a more suitable (and more readable and more maintainable(!)) solution to your problem than one huge unreadable regular expression.

Comment: @Heinzi Thank for responding. This is a validation that happens on client side how can we write an if statement. I believe we can write a onkeypress function and call the javascript function to handle if statements. Am I correct?

Comment: @bhargavakrishnachunduri: Yes, that's one option. This is a wide topic, here is an article to start: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation